# No animation with some sensors in the BGE

Tags: animation, game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a problem with the Action Actuator and animations in BGE. I would like to play an animation. 
It works only when I use the "Always" and "Delay" sensors but I need the "Radar" and the "Near" sensors. 
But if I use the Near sensor no animation is playing. Here is a picture of my Logic Bricks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to change the true level triggering (pulse mode)

[image: pulse mode]

if that not works, maybe at the physics tab click on the actor checkbox there

[image]